# Reg expression - split string between matching strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get an array of strings, from a lengthy string. Array consist of strings matching between two other strings (`???` and `???` in my case). I tried the following code and it's not giving me the expected results

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\?\\?\\?(.*?)\\?\\?\\?");
    String[] arrayOfKeys = pattern.split("???label.missing???sdfjkhsjkdf sjkdghfjksdg ???some.label???sdjkhsdj");

    for (String key : arrayOfKeys) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

My expected result is:

```
["label.missing", "some.label"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.matcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to obtain a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for the input string, then use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to find the pattern you want. `Matcher.find()` will find substring(s) that matches the `Pattern` provided.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\?{3}(.*?)\\?{3}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputString);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[`Pattern.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) will use your pattern as delimiter to split the string (then the delimiter part is discarded), which is obviously not what you want in this case. Your regex is designed to match the text that you want to extract.

I shorten the pattern to use quantifier *repeating exactly 3 times* `{3}`, instead of writing `\?` 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a string input with what you're trying to split, and call input.split() on it.

```
String input = "???label.missing???sdfjkhsjkdf sjkdghfjksdg ???some.label???sdjkhsdj";
String[] split = input.split("\\?\\?\\?");
```

Try it here:
http://ideone.com/VAmCyu

Comment: How would you identify the junk items from the desired items?

Comment: Oh, only the labels are desired? You could take every other one?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\?{3}(.+?)\\?{3}");
    Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher("???label.missing???sdfjkhsjkdf sjkdghfjksdg ???some.label???sdjkhsdj");

     List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

     while(matcher.find()) {
         aList.add(matcher.group(1));
     }


    for (String key : aList) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```